# using <input> outside a <form> php

Tags: php, html

I have a button that creates a folder if it doesn't exist called "create folder" and a button that deletes a folder if it exists called "delete folder".

How can I set up the buttons so when they are clicked the do what they are meant to do without putting the buttons inside a form with method=post?

Because I was using $_POST['deleteFo'] to pick up when the button is clicked on.

```
<?php
$dir = scandir("uploads/admin@admin.com");

foreach($dir as $rows){
    if ($rows == "." || $rows == ".."){
    } else {
        if(is_dir("uploads/admin@admin.com/".$rows)){
            echo "Folder: $rows <br>";
        } else {
            echo "File: $rows <br>";
        }
    }
}
?>
<form method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="createFo" value="Create Folder" id="CreateFolderBtn"/>
    <?php 
        if (isset($_POST['createFo'])){
            if (is_dir('uploads/admin@admin.com/examples')) {
                echo "Examples Already Exists!";
            } else {
                mkdir('uploads/admin@admin.com/examples');
                header('Refresh: 0');
            }
            echo "Examples Created!";
        } else {echo "nop1";}
    ?>
    <input type="submit" name="deleteFo" value="Delete Folder" id="DeleteFolderBtn"/>
    <?php 
        if (isset($_POST['deleteFo'])){
            if(!is_dir('uploads/admin@admin.com/examples')){
                echo "Examples Forder doesn't exist!";
            } else {
                rmdir('uploads/admin@admin.com/examples');
                header('Refresh: 0');
            }
            echo "Examples Folder Deleted!";
        } else {echo "nop2";}
    ?>
</form>
```

Output:

```
Folder: New_Folder 
File: Thumbs.db 
File: Untitled.wma 
Folder: pics 
File: screenshot (4).png 
File: screenshot.png 
File: screenshot_(2).png 
File: screenshot_(3).png 
//button -> [Create Folder] nop1 //button -> [Delete Folder] nop2
```

Comment: If you want to perform a server action based on client actions you must use a `form` or use `javascript` + `ajax`

Comment: What do the buttons do?  Is it a client-side action or a server-side action?

Comment: What is the reason you don't want it in a form?

Comment: A form can have multiple `submits`, just name them differently and check which one was pressed in PHP.

Comment: I edited with the code, however what I mean is if I want to have buttons in different elements/divs I'm bound to using the form

Comment: What exactly happens when you run this code?

Comment: check the question updated it again